# How to extract var from query string and write it (echo) into the html?

Tags: php, query-string, dynamic-keyword

I want to take var1 and var2 out of the query string and write it (echo) into the HTML.

Seems simple, but my URL needs to be formed like this:

```
http://example.com/filename.html#var1=FOO&var2=BAR
```

Notice **the hash after the filename** -- URL does not contain normal `?` query string delimiter.

How do I accomplish this with a simple function? ... seems like a basic question, but I can't get it to work with URL syntax that requires # before ?.

thanks in advance!

**UPDATE UPDATE UDATE** - building on the code example in @Musa's answer.

I want to grab the PHP_URL_FRAGMENTS from the window location, and write them into the HTML, I am attempting this:

```
// get the URL from window location:
$pageURL = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$pageURL .= $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '80' ? $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
return $pageURL;

// parse URL including #fragments:
parse_str (parse_url ($pageURL, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT ), $args);

// write var values into the HTML:
    echo $args['var1'], ' ', $args['var2'];
```

I'm either not creating `$pageURL` properly, or I'm doing something wrong in the `parse_str` line.

Still working with an URL syntax that looks like this: `http://example.com/filename.html#var1=FOO&var2=BAR`

Any solutions from you wizards? Thank you.

Comment: So you need a solution for a necessarily invalid URL? Why must the `#` exist there?

Comment: For google analytics & pagerank purposes. Google, when indexing pages, ignores anything after the `#` in the URL. So it treats `http://example.com/pagename.html` &  `http://example.com/pagename.html#somefragment` as the same page. HOWEVER, it sees `http://example.com/pagename.html` & `http://example.com/pagename.html?var1=foo&var2=bar` as TWO DIFFERENT pages, so you are diluting link juice & polluting your anaytics. Google supports `#` as query string delim [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setAllowAnchor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parse_str (parse_url ("http://example.com/filename.html#var1=FOO&var2=BAR", PHP_URL_FRAGMENT ), $args);
echo $args['var1'], $args['var2'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/oi0fr)

Comment: Problem is, the fragment isn't passed to the server, so that full URI won't be available to PHP strictly from the request itself.

Comment: OK, you are a rockstar. But I want to grab the fragments from the window location. I've updated my question, based on your code example, but I think it needs a small tweak to make it work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RoweMorehouse fragment aren't sent in request so you don't have access to it on the server, you have to include some client side logic

Comment: Best answer, but I stil l have not solved my problem; I need client side logic to extract hash. Trying javascript-only solution. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it through Javascript or send it to server as a hidden form element.

The part after sharp symbol (hash part) usually will not be passed to the server by browser.

You can check your server logs - received get requests will be "http://example.com/filename.html", but not "http://example.com/filename.html#?var1=FOO&var2=BAR"

Comment: Thanks, good answer. I know I can grab the URL from window location with javascript like this `<script>alert(window.location);</script>` but I'm trying to stay with a pure PHP solution right now if possible.